# Adding Trading session time in Pine Script v5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to initiate trade 10 minutes once the exchange opens (i.e., at 0925) and closes all open positions (Universal exit) 10 minutes before the exchange closes (i.e., at 01520). How can I do that? Please help.

I tried:

tradeTimes = input.session("0925-1520", title="Trading Times") But its not working.

Then tried:

session = input("0925-1520") t = time(timeframe.period, session)

As a result in the dialogue box a new label "input" appeared in which the session time was mentioned but trades were not taken accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the session information you get from the use input to the `time()` function.

```
session_time = input.session("1200-1500", "Session")
is_in_session = time(timeframe.period, session_time + ":1234567")
```

Then use `is_in_session` as part of your entry condition. You can do the same for your exits.

**Note:** `time()` will use your exchange`s timezone. If you need a different timezone, you can pass the timezone information as a third parameter.

```
time(timeframe, session, timezone) → series int
```

For example:

```
is_in_session = time(timeframe.period, session_time + ":1234567", "GMT+1")
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Though still trying to understand the codes you mentioned!! I'm new to Pine Script (and even programming). BTW my time zone is GMT +5.30.

Comment: As per your suggestion I added:

session_time = input.session("0925-1520", "Session")
is_in_session = time(timeframe.period, session_time)

longEntryCondition = (is_in_session) and ta.crossover(ema10Close, ema20Close) 
longCloseCondition = (is_in_session) and ta.crossunder(ema20Close, ema10Close) 

shortEntryCondition = (is_in_session) and ta.crossunder(ema10Close , ema20Close) 
shortCloseCondition = (is_in_session) and ta.crossover(ema10Close, ema20Close)  BUT NOT SURE (1) IF THE OPEN POSITIONS ARE CLOSED BY 1520 HRS & (2) NEXT POSITION IS TAKEN ONLY WHEN THE PREVIOUS ONE IS CLOSED.